# Storing credentials with Siesta framework - iOS

Tags: ios, swift, siesta-swift

Wanted to give to Siesta a try and I've started using it within a side project.

I was wondering if any of you have got any advice about storing the login credentials (either username+psw or just the token) and how these have been integrated within the API structure proposed by Siesta.

Did you simply use the KeychainItemWrapper? Something else worth sharing?

Thanks ;)

Comment: FWIW, credential storage is entirely independent of Siesta. Siesta makes a point of keeping its nose out of that stuff. Use any strategy you want, and just make sure you invalidate Siesta’s config if credentials change. Imagine this, except in addition to the Siesta, it also saves the value: https://github.com/bustoutsolutions/siesta/blob/master/Examples/GithubBrowser/Source/API/GithubAPI.swift#L131-L142

Comment: Hey, @PaulCantrell, thanks for responding to this. Yeah, I thought the same, I'd probably go with storing them using the keychain wrapper and eventually build something on top of that later on ;)